# How to access the JSON object outside the Fetch API response?

Tags: javascript

I am currently having a problem accessing `emoji_map` outside of the `then` scope and I don't know how to do it.

Here's my code:

```
if (req) {
    fetch(req).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(response) {
    /* start to observe */
    emoji_map = response.emoji_map;
    console.log(emoji_map);
    });

}
```

When I do console.log(emoji_map); outside if loop I cannot access the response assigned. Can anyone help?

Comment: Make sure you understand asynchronous javascript, there are many articles and tutorials.

Comment: You can't access a variable before it's available, which is precisely, and only, within the `then` scope.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read more about JavaScript lexical scoping and closures on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures.

> ```
> function init() {
>   var name = "Mozilla"; // name is a local variable created by init
>   function displayName() { // displayName() is the inner function, a closure
>     alert(name); // use variable declared in the parent function    
>   }
>   displayName();    
> }
> init();
> ```
>
> init() creates a local variable name and then a function called
>   displayName(). displayName() is an inner function that is defined
>   inside init() and is only available within the body of that function.
>   displayName() has no local variables of its own, however it has access
>   to the variables of outer functions and so can use the variable name
>   declared in the parent function.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with closures. It has to do with accessing an asynchronously-available value in a context before it is available.

Comment: The question wasn't exactly extra-clear. I thought his problem was that the variable was undefined, even after the promise was resolved.

Comment: Right. But how do you know that the promise was resolved unless you're in the part of your code (the `then` handler) which is by definition where it is known to have been resolved?

Comment: You can have multiple handlers for the same promise. If you define a variable in one handler, it is undefined in the other.

Answer (score 0):

What you can declare a global variable outside your fetch statement, and fill the response in that variable, say in your case

```
          var sampleData;
          if (req) {
            fetch(req).then(function(response) {
               sampleData = response.json();
               return response.json();
            }).then(function(response) {
                 /* start to observe */
                 emoji_map = sampleData.emoji_map;
                 console.log(emoji_map);
             });

          }

     OR 

      fetch('https://davidwalsh.name/some/url').then(function(response) {
           return //...
        }).then(function(returnedValue) {
         // ...
       }).catch(function(err) {
           // Error :(
       });
```

you can try the above code or refer  [this](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch)

Comment: This fails to understand the very fundamentals of asynchronicity.